# Getting both gross and net totals from a column in a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to get both a gross and net sum of the values in a certain column in a data.table. By gross sum, I mean ignoring negative values, so that for `a` in this example, the net sum is 4, and the gross sum is 5.

```
>dt = data.table(id = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c"),value = c(-1,2,3,-3,4,-2,3,-1,1))
>head(dt,3)
   id value
1:  a    -1
2:  a     2
3:  a     3
```

I can do it by adding an extra column, like this:

```
>dt$grossValue = dt$value
>dt$grossValue[dt$grossValue < 0] = 0
>dt[,.(netTotal = sum(value),grossTotal= sum(grossValue)),by=id]
   id netTotal grossTotal
1:  a        4          5
2:  b        2          7
3:  c        0          1
```

But I don't really want to have to add an extra column to the data, as there are millions of rows, and I might want to do this across multiple columns. is there a way of doing it directly? I can figure out how to get either gross total or net total (getting gross total by adding `value > 0` in `i`), but not both at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
dt[, .(netTotal = sum(value), grossTotal = sum(value * (value > 0))), by=id]
```

I calculated both columns in one pass. `(value > 0)` is used as a logical to remove negative values from the `sum`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Relatively inexperienced with R, and not familiar with this idiom. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I apparently misunderstood the request because I thought you were asking for grand totals as well. So here's that gratuitous solution:

```
rbind( dt[,.(netTotal = sum(value),grossTotal= sum(value*(value>0))),by=id],
 data.table( id="all", netTotal=dt[,sum(value)], grossTotal=dt[,sum(value*(value>0))]))
#-------------
    id netTotal grossTotal
1:   a        4          5
2:   b        2          7
3:   c        0          1
4: all        6         13
```

Answer (score 0):

are you familiar with the dplyr package? If not, check it out, it makes tasks like these pretty simple once you get the hang of it.

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(net = sum(value), gross = sum(ifelse(value > 0, value, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also subset instead of multiplying by logical index

```
dt[, .(netTotal = sum(value), grossTotal = sum(value[value>0])) , id]
#   id netTotal grossTotal
#1:  a        4          5
#2:  b        2          7
#3:  c        0          1
```